# how to show another image until the gif is fully loaded?

Tags: html, gif

in the first block of the site I have a large gif image that takes a very long time to load.

```html
<picture>
            <source srcset="https://media.githubusercontent.com/media/javascripteaser88/fintech-          
            remake/main/media/vapor.gif" type="image/gif" media="(min-width:501px)">
            <source srcset="https://media.githubusercontent.com/media/javascripteaser88/fintech-remake/main/media/mobile.gif" type="image/gif" media="(max-width:501px)">
            <img src="https://media.githubusercontent.com/media/javascripteaser88/fintech-remake/main/media/vapor.gif"alt="outrun gif" class="outrun">
</picture>
```

it looks very bad when the user has to wait a few tens of seconds before seeing the content (and someone's gif won't even load completely).

So I need to show some kind of lightweight image until my gif animation is fully loaded, or just show the first frame of this animation, but i don't know how to do it. Or you can advise some other ways to reduce the waiting time that I did not expect.

P.S. here is a link to the site hosted on github pages https://javascripteaser88.github.io/fintech-remake/

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40746776/how-to-load-a-small-placeholder-image-before-loading-the-actual-content). Using `background-image` and a lightweight image you can have a placeholder show while the real image loads.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to load a small placeholder image before loading the actual content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40746776/how-to-load-a-small-placeholder-image-before-loading-the-actual-content)

Comment: no, now it's all just loading for even longer or does it work the same way

Comment: `<picture>
<source src="https://media.githubusercontent.com/media/javascripteaser88/fintech-remake/main/media/vapor.gif"  data-src="media/Comet.webp" onload="if(this.src !== this.getAttribute('data-src')) this.src=this.getAttribute('data-src');" type="image/gif" media="(min-width:501px)"> `